# Material tree parent node not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have done a material tree selectable, with a limit of 42 elements selectable. When I reach the limit (42), the nodes become disabled. The problem is that when I reach the limit and I have from a family some childs selected and some disabled, the parent node is partially selected, so it works weird when I manually deselect a child, and select the parent node again.

[image]

Image above is not correct. Parent node should be marked as "All selected"

[image]

Image above is correct

[image]

This is what happens when I deselect a child, select parent and deselect parent.
And here's the code.

```
  descendantsAllSelected(productNodeFlat: ProductNodeFlat): boolean {
    if (this.treeControl.dataNodes) {
      const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(productNodeFlat);
      return descendants.every(child => this.productNodeFlatSelection.isSelected(child));
    }
    return false;
  }

  descendantsPartiallySelected(productNodeFlat: ProductNodeFlat): boolean {
    if (this.treeControl.dataNodes) {
      const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(productNodeFlat);
      const result = descendants.some(child => this.productNodeFlatSelection.isSelected(child));
      return result && !this.descendantsAllSelected(productNodeFlat);
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'all selected' function needs to consider whether or not the node is disabled, since all selected means that all of the children are either selected *or disabled*. I don't know how you store the disabled state, so I am using `child.disabled` here to represent that. Something like:

```
descendantsAllSelected(productNodeFlat: ProductNodeFlat): boolean {
  if (this.treeControl.dataNodes) {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(productNodeFlat);
    return descendants.every(child => 
      this.productNodeFlatSelection.isSelected(child) || child.disabled
    );
  }

  return false;
}
```

Another way to do that would be to check if the number of selections is equal to the maximum allowable.

Your 'partially selected' function also needs to consider whether or not the node is 'disabled', and you can also improve the efficiency by simply checking for the first one selected and first one not selected and not disabled. This requires only one iteration through the nodes:

```
descendantsPartiallySelected(productNodeFlat: ProductNodeFlat): boolean {
  if (this.treeControl.dataNodes) {
    let selected = false;
    let unselected = false;
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(productNodeFlat);
    return descendants.some(child => {
      if (this.productNodeFlatSelection.isSelected(child)) {
        selected = true;
      }
      else if (!child.disabled) {
        notselected = true;
      }
      return selected && notselected;
    });
  }

  return false;
}
```